# Laravel default user migration

Tags: mysql, laravel, authentication, laravel-6, laravel-migrations

I am trying to use Laravel to set up the required database tables.
Using the documented:

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table;
php artisan migrate;
```

However, this generates a simple three-column table:

```
id
created_at
updated_at
```

Authentication (default Laravel setup) requires obvious fields such as email and password, meaning an error when trying to use 'out of the box' authentication:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in
>   'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where
>   `email` =

I am missing something here, I would have thought that to use the preset authentication scaffolding, Laravel would set up the database correctly.

What should I be running to do this from the outset?

Comment: Laravel already provides the correct migration in https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/master/database/migrations you probably overwrote it

Comment: The problem was it seemed to create the correct migrations once and then just the basic 3 columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact you don't need to create this migration. By default in fresh Laravel installation you have created user migrations so you can just run

```
php artisan migrate
```

to run this migration.

Default users migration is [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php) and all 3 default migrations can be found [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/master/database/migrations).

And in case you create custom new migration then it contains just id and timestamps (created_at/updated_at) so you should edit such migration file to put columns you want

Comment: Thanks, this is unexpected behaviour for me, would have thought it would create any REQUIRED columns in a table. I did indeed delete them due to a Class already defined error